# Pandas OLS Regression Results not matching up

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda, regression

I am plotting a regression test for my assignment, however the R-squared and Adjusted R-squared parameters are not matching up with what they are expected to be. I am stumped as to why they don't like up like they should.

```
if indep_variable in annual_processed.columns and dep_variable in annual_processed.columns:
    # Select data within the specified years
    # Ensure 'yyyy' is the index
    annual_processed.set_index('yyyy', inplace=True)

    # Apply the mask and select the desired columns
    data_selection = annual_processed.loc[mask, [indep_variable, dep_variable]].dropna().reset_index()
    data_selection = data_selection[(data_selection['yyyy'] >= start_year) & (data_selection['yyyy'] <= end_year)]

    # Ensuring our data types are numbers

    print(data_selection.dtypes)
    if len(data_selection) > 1:
        #avg = data_selection.loc[start_year:end_year, dep_variable].mean(skipna=True)
        #IS_error_N = data_selection.loc[start_year:end_year, dep_variable] - avg
        
        X = data_selection[indep_variable].values
        X = sm.add_constant(X)  # Add a constant term for the intercept
        y = data_selection[dep_variable].values

        model = sm.OLS(y, X)
```